# EF SaveChanges method throws: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

When i save an order from my winforms app it works ok. But when i try to add a second one the SaveChanges() method throws an exception:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

I have one table "Orders" and one "Orderlines" that has a foreignkey OrderID.

Does anyone know why this happens?

I know that my context handling is not ideal, so if that is the problem, any suggestions on how to change this would be much obliged!

```
public class Orders
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public Orders()
    {
        _context = EntityContext.Context;
    }

    public int Save(Order order)
    {
        if (order.ID > 0)
            _context.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
        else
        {
            _context.Orders.Add(order);
        } 
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return order.ID;
    }
}
public class EntityContext : IDisposable
{
    private static DataContext _context;
    public static DataContext Context
    {
        get
        {
            if (_context != null)
                return _context;
            return _context = new DataContext();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1** Added Order class and screencapture of order on exceptiontime

I have set update integrity to CASCADE.

Orderlines is a relationship table.

```
public partial class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        this.Orderlines = new HashSet<Orderline>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int PaymentType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SettlementID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> CashPayment { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> BankPayment { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UserID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Orderline> Orderlines { get; set; }
    public virtual Settlement Settlement { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Object order on exception]

**EDIT 2** - Partial classes

I have partial classes extending the order and orderline objects:

```
public partial class Order 
{
    public decimal Total
    {
        get { return Orderlines.Sum(x => x.Quantity*x.Price); }
    }
    public decimal TotalExMva
    {
        get { return Orderlines.Sum(x => (x.Quantity*x.Price)/(x.Vat + 1)); }
    }
    public decimal Mva
    {
        get { return Total - TotalExMva; }
    }

}

public partial class Orderline
{
    public decimal Total
    {
        get { return (Price*Quantity); }         
    }

    public string ProductName
    {

        get
        {
            var currentProductId = ProductID;
            return new Products().Get(currentProductId).Name;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3** - orderline and product classes

```
public partial class Orderline
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Vat { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.Orderlines = new HashSet<Orderline>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string GTIN { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Vat { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Orderline> Orderlines { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Orderlines -> Orderline object at exception]

Comment: This normally happens if an NavigationProperty which is (in sql)marked with ReferentialIntegrity has no value What does your order object look like?

Comment: @Grumbler85 I have edited my post with some additional data. As to the ReferentialIntegrity I will read up on that.

Comment: I would check **SettlementID** and/or **UserID** - null values allowed? relation to?

Comment: SettlementID and UserID are forreignkeys and has allow null set.

Comment: What about the orderline object (I saw count=1)? Does this orderline Object refer to the shown order object?

Comment: The order contains a list of orderlines. I'll add the orderline object class in EDIT 3. Orderlines has its own table in the DB.

Comment: add a `try catch block` - and have a look at the **innerException** of the invalidOperationException. This type sometimes offers some more detailed information about what was going wrong!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35200/discussion-between-pilgerstorfer-franz-and-espvar)

Answer (score -1):

This is well described in this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2010/01/31/deleting-foreign-key-relationships-in-ef4.aspx

and is a problem known as an identifying relationship: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee373856(v=vs.100).aspx

TRex

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.